# JSP fn:split function is not working as expected if the first portion of the string is missing

Tags: jsp

The following piece of JSP code splits a string using a pipe character.

```
      <c:set var="strings" value="${fn:split(originalString,'|')}"/>
      <c:set var="firstString" value="${strings[0]}"/>
      <c:set var="secondString" value="${strings[1]}"/>
```

If originalString has a value ,say, 'abc|def', it works ok. firstString will be abc and secondString will be def

But if originalString is equal to '|abcdef', then the firstString is having value 'abcdef'.

Why is this so? I had to use a scriplet to work around this issue. Is this a with fn library?

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer is internally used by fn:split. Please refer to [the specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jstl-1.1-mr2-spec-oth-JSpec/).

Behavior of "fn:split" is the same as:

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("|abcdef", "|");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
      System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
```

Output:

```
abcdef
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I could not find any reason from the specs for this odd behaviour

Comment: I have added the detail to my answer.

Comment: You may have to use fn:startsWith, for example:

      <c:set var="firstString" value="${fn:startsWith(originalString, '|') ? '' : fn:split(originalString, '|')[0]}"/>

      <c:set var="secondString" value="${fn:startsWith(originalString, '|') ? fn:split(originalString, '|')[0] : fn:split(originalString, '|')[1]}"/>